Scrutor register all classes that use an interface?
I have many command classes. They all are defined like this:
public class TestCommand() : AbstractRoomChatCommand
{
    public override string Trigger => "test";
    
    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRoomUser user, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractRoomChatCommand : IRoomChatCommand 
{
    public abstract string Trigger { get; }
}

I'm trying to register them all like so:
serviceCollection.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblies()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IRoomChatCommand>())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithSingletonLifetime());

